# Code executing before async/await function finishes?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, ecmascript-6, promise, fetch

I'm new to asynchronous programming and I'm trying to understand async/await with ES6. I have the following code:

```
import "isomorphic-fetch";

const url = "https://randomuser.me/api/";
const user = [];

console.time('fetching');
const request = async() => {
    const data = await fetch(url);
    const json = await data.json();
    return json;
}
request()
    .then(data => console.timeEnd('fetching'))
    .then(data => user.push(data))
    .catch(error => console.log("There was an error fetching the data: \n", error));

request();
console.log(user);
```

My problem is that the console log happens before the data has finished being fetched, so I get the following result:

```
[]
fetching: 255.277ms
```

The way I understand it is that the `request()` function should be performed before moving on to the following line, but it doesn't apparently work this way.

What do I need to do to get the code to wait until `request()` has finished before performing the `console.log(user)`?

Comment: you don't. that's not how this works. Move the console.log into a callback that gets called once the work is done. An async function is still asynchronous. You still have to wait for it to complete.

Comment: The entire point of asynchronous code is that it doesn't wait. If you want to log after `request` is done, chain your logging code via `.then` just like the other lambdas.

Comment: A function will only wait for function to complete if it is called with the ```await``` keyword. The ```await``` keyword can only be used inside an ```async``` function. Therefore, you can not ```await``` for a function to complete in the global (topmost) scope.

Answer (score 2):

Your issue is that you are mixing asynchronous and synchronous code. You would need to `await` or `then` the `request` call you want to wait for.

One option would be to move your code into an `async` function and then call it.

```
import "isomorphic-fetch";

const url = "https://randomuser.me/api/";
const user = [];

console.time('fetching');
const request = async() => {
    const data = await fetch(url);
    const json = await data.json();
    return json;
}

async function main() {
    await request()
        .then(data => console.timeEnd('fetching'))
        .then(data => user.push(data))
        .catch(error => console.log("There was an error fetching the data: \n", error));

    console.log(user);
}
main();
```

If you do this, you can also rewrite your `then` and `catch` methods into a simpler try/catch statement.

```
import "isomorphic-fetch";

const url = "https://randomuser.me/api/";
const user = [];

console.time('fetching');
const request = async() => {
    const data = await fetch(url);
    const json = await data.json();
    return json;
}

async function main() {
    try {
        const data = await request();
        console.timeEnd('fetching');
        user.push(data);
    }
    catch (err) {
        console.log("There was an error fetching the data: \n", error)
    }

    console.log(user);
}
main();
```

Comment: You'll probably want to use `await` instead of `then` inside `main`

Comment: @Bergi Good call.